# How to add Chrome Extension icon to Chrome Web Store (new dashboard)

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I published a new Chrome Extension through the [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole/) but i don't know where to add the extension which shows in the store. In the old developer dashboard there was a separate option, but in the new dashboard I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no icon menu in new chrome developer dashboard.

Change your location of icons to root of package zip file,
(same level with manifest.json file)
and rename icon files to `icon_xx.png`.
('xx' should be 16, 48, and 128)

Fix 'icon' property of your extension's `manifest.json`.

Then, after you submit your package, chrome store will recognize icons automatically.

Comment: What a downgrade from how it previously worked. Now I need to have my extension reviewed again because the images are not at the same level as manifest.json